# couldn't match expected type [a0] with actual type IO ()

Tags: haskell, syntax

What is wrong in my code:

```
insertValue file x = 
    if x == "10" then "ok"
    else do putStrLn "Error"; file
```

Answer (score 2):

In an `if..then..else` expression, both branches have to have the same type.

One branch is:

```
"10" :: String
```

The other branch is:

```
do putStrLn "Error"; file :: IO ??
```

Since I'm not sure what you're trying to do (and the compiler isn't sure either), I don't know how to correct the code.

Comment: For example insertValue "99" "10" should return "ok". insertValue "99" "5" should print "Error" and return "99".

Comment: @newuser: In Haskell, you can't just do some IO (or anything else in a monad) and then go on as if you merely did some pure computations. Once a function touches `IO`, it's "tainted" and must return an `IO` value as well.

Comment: @newuser: Yes, you can. Use `return` to convert a pure value into an IO-tainted value. e.g. `return "ok"` and `return file`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `return :: a -> IO a` to "lift" your strings into `IO String`:

```
insertValue file x = 
    if x == "10"
      then return "ok"
      else do putStrLn "Error"
              return file
```

But are you sure you don't want to call `putStrLn "ok"` (instead of `return "ok"`) and return a Maybe value?  Otherwise you are returning `file` or `"ok"` and your caller could never determine if there was an error when calling `insertValue` on a file named "ok".

Answer (score 1):

"ok" is of type "String" while the "else" clause is of type "IO ()".  In Haskell "if" is an expression, so they have to match.

Its difficult to help more without knowing what you are trying to do.