# couldn't match expected type

Tags: haskell

I would like to do something different but it would be too long so below is only example:

```
test x y = if x == "5" then x
           else do putStrLn "bad value"; y
```

so if x == 5 it should return x, else it should print 'bad value' and return y - how can I do that in haskell ?

---

**edit:**

Why this code returns error: "couldn't match expected type bool with actual type IO bool" ?

```
canTest :: String -> IO Bool
canTest x = if x == "5" then return True
           else do putStrLn "bad value"; return False

test x y = if canTest x then x
           else y
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [couldn't match expected type \[a0\] with actual type IO ()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087111/couldnt-match-expected-type-a0-with-actual-type-io)

Comment: Please don't open a new question on the exact same problem. Rather edit your old one our ask something new. If you need such kind of a debug printf, [hoogle](http://haskell.org/hoogle/) for `trace`.

Answer (score 6):

You need to make both sides have the same type, namely `IO String`.  For this you need to use `return` to lift the values into the monad, i.e.

```
test :: String -> String -> IO String
test x y = if x == "5"
             then return x
             else do putStrLn "bad value"
                     return y
```

Now `return x` has the type `IO String`, and so does the `do` block in the else branch.

Comment: hm...... in other function in which I have: x2 <- test x, I have error: occurs check cannot construct the infinite type b0 IO b0

Comment: @newuser: Your function `test` takes two arguments. The place were you call it with just one argument is where the compiler rejects your code.

Comment: sry - my mistake - but could you look at my first post and edit part - i have next error :/

Comment: newuser: You can't extinguish `IO`. Whenever you're using IO somewhere, it has to be carried up the whole function tree. Think functional! Try to distinguish the places, where you want to do IO from those where you compute. If you want to have the "debug-print", have a look at `trace`.

Comment: So I must specify in each function types with IO ? :( :( This isn't comfortable.

Comment: @newuser. Yes. The alternative is to use `trace`, which does not requires IO (But is designed for debugging purposes) or to stop using such code at all.

Answer (score 0):

Because `canTest` has side-effects (i.e. does I/O), its return type is `IO Bool`, which has two implications:

1. You cannot test its value directly in the if predicate, you must 'run' the action first, then test the extracted value.
2. Your edited `test` function must also be in the IO monad, as you cannot escape IO. (Unless very carefully with `unsafePerformIO`)

   ```
   canTest :: String -> IO Bool
   canTest x = if x == "5"
                 then return True
                 else do putStrLn "bad value"; return False

   test :: String -> String -> IO String
   test x y = do xCanTest <- canTest x
                 if xCanTest
                   then return x
                   else return y
   ```

Results in

```
Prelude> test "5" "12"
"5"
Prelude> test "6" "12"
bad value
"12"
```

Comment: thx but that's mean that I must change all my 29 functions :( eh.... no other way ?

Comment: @newuser No, you don't want to change your 29 functions to have IO in the type.  That's the wrong way.